# How to find number in long int with binary representing? C++

Tags: c++, binary, find

If we have classical **decimal format** in int long, we can do something like that:

```
const long int NUMBER = 4577;         
const long int DIGIT_TO_FIND = 5;

long int thisNumber = NUMBER >= 0 ? NUMBER : -NUMBER; 
long int thisDigit;

while (thisNumber != 0)
{
    thisDigit = thisNumber % 10;    
    thisNumber = thisNumber / 10;    
    if (thisDigit == DIGIT_TO_FIND)
    {
        printf("%d contains digit %d", NUMBER, DIGIT_TO_FIND);
        break;
    }
}
```

But what about **binary representing** or **octal representing** in **int long**?
We have:

```
const long int NUMBER = 01011111; // octal
const long int DIGIT_TO_FIND1 = 0;         
const long int DIGIT_TO_FIND2 = 1;
```

*Correct input*:

```
01010101
11111111
```

*Bad input*:

```
02010101 (because two)
00000009 (because nine)
```

We need to check if **int long contains only 0 or 1**.
What is the simpliest way to check correct input for that? Maybe just easy question, but no idea, thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you want here.
You want to check that the decimal representation of a number 'x' contains only 1s and 0s? Because if you represented it in binary it by definition will have...

Comment: @J99 I think he has a long with a number consisting of ones and zeros which although is a decimal is actually a binary number. He then wants to verify that the digits are 1/0 only... why I don't know!

Comment: So, we have: 
const `long int NUMBER = 01011111;`
That is correct, because contains only 0 or 1. The wrong input will be something like: `long int NUMBER = 01011112;`

Comment: To re-state @Caribou he has a string which should contain only `'0'` and `'1'` and wants to interpret it as a binary number returning an error if disallowed digits occur, so `man strtol`.

Comment: @RePRO That code does a well defined thing (which isn't what you want) and you can't change it. Think instead of functions and classes.

Comment: @dmckee is it a string? I didn't see that otherwise I'd have answered by now....

Comment: @Caribou Well...I *thought* so, but now I'm not sure the problem is well defined.

Comment: @RePRO You probably have not initialized the number you think you have (`01011111 == 266825`). See this article on integer literals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I know, my mistake, thanks for that. 
@moooeeeep, Pubby: Leading zero specifies octal constant, not decimal.

Comment: @RePRO apart from chmod (rarely) i've nvr used octal - totally passed me by

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a digit is a valid binary digit, compare it with `1`:

```
if (thisDigit > 1)
{
    printf("%d contains digit %d", NUMBER, thisDigit);
    break;
}
```

As noted by @Pubby, you have an octal number instead of a decimal number, so use `8` instead of `10` to calculate digits:

```
thisDigit = thisNumber % 8;    
thisNumber = thisNumber / 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question something like this -

```
#include <iostream>

bool check(int number, int search_1, int search_2)
{
    while(number > 0)
    {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number    = number / 10;
        if (digit != search_1 && digit != search_2)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const int DIGIT_TO_FIND1 = 0;
    const int DIGIT_TO_FIND2 = 1;

    int number1 = 1001001;
    std::cout << "Checking " << number1 << " : " << check(number1, DIGIT_TO_FIND1, DIGIT_TO_FIND2) <<" \n";

    int number2 = 12110101;
    std::cout << "Checking " << number2 << " : " << check(number2, DIGIT_TO_FIND1, DIGIT_TO_FIND2) <<" \n";
}
```

Comment: Thas is not clear solution, try check `int number1 = 0001001;` and does not works. ;) Cause octal.

Comment: Well don't do that then! To be clear, I mean what can be done about that? You have to know some c++ to use the language, if you want to input a number like this don't use octal:P

Comment: But that is correct: `int number1 = 0001001`, cause contains 0 or 1.

Comment: I agree with the problem, but the question isn't clearly defined about what he wants to answer it well.

Comment: I figured it out. Look at my solution. Thank you for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. It's really simple.

```
   bool check(int long number)
   {
     return ((number % 10 != 0) && (number % 10) != 1);
   }
```

Comment: You only check the very last (base-10) digit of that number in a otherwise not-very-reusable implementation. Is this really to be your final solution?